# É possível alterar o valor de uma anotação em tempo de execução?

Tags: java, reflexão, annotation

Considerando a anotação seguinte:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MinhaAnotacao {
   String valor();
}
```

Definida em uma classe:

```
@MinhaAnotacao(valor = "algum valor")
class ExemploStackOverflow {
}
```

Sei que é possível obter o valor do campo `valor` em tempo de execução, OK.
Mas é possível alterar esse valor também? Por exemplo:

```
ExemploStackOverflow exemplo = new ExemploStackOverflow();

// Exibe "algum valor"
System.out.println(exemplo.getClass().getAnnotation(MinhaAnotacao.class).valor());

// Chama algum método que altera o conteúdo do campo "valor" da anotação.
AnnotacoesUtils.mudarValor(exemplo, "novo valor");

// Exibiria "novo valor"
System.out.println(exemplo.getClass().getAnnotation(MinhaAnotacao.class).valor());
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isto?

Encontrei [uma possível solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276270/4056678) no StackOverflow que parece ser gambiarra. Mas ela não funciona na versão 8 do Java, é lançada uma exceção ao chamar:

```
Field field = Class.class.getDeclaredField("annotations");
```

Comment: O que você está querendo fazer não é uma boa prática. Achei esse link que pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089290/change-annotation-value-of-field-annotation-in-java-8

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível mudar a anotação em si, mas se um campo da anotação é uma classe, é possível alterar os campos estáticos dela.

Anotação:

```
package teste.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;    

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Anota {

    Class<? extends AnotaValue> value();
}
```

Classe que será o valor da Anotação:

```
package teste.annotation;

public class AnotaValue {

    public static String valor = "velho";
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
package teste.annotation;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Anota(AnotaValue.class)
public class Exemplo {

Field getCampoAnotado() throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Anota annotation = this.getClass().getAnnotation(Anota.class);
    return annotation.value().getDeclaredField("valor");
}

String getValorDoCampoAnotado() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    return (String) getCampoAnotado().get(null);
}

void setValorDoCampoAnotado(String valor) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    getCampoAnotado().set(null, valor);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Exemplo exemplo = new Exemplo();
    Logger.getLogger(Exemplo.class.getName()).info(exemplo.getValorDoCampoAnotado());
    exemplo.setValorDoCampoAnotado("novo");
    Logger.getLogger(Exemplo.class.getName()).info(exemplo.getValorDoCampoAnotado());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que não. As anotações são transformadas em instruções em tempo de compilação e os valores tornados constantes. Você até pode hackear para que apresente o valor que quiser, mas isso não altera a anotação em si, apenas o que é mostrado. Por isso, como disse o @Fagner-Fonseca, não é boa prática.